# Graphical game using vb.bet

Tags: vb.net

I have been coding in vb.net for business purposes, however because I like to play video games I was wondering if it is possible to build graphical video games such as Mario Brothers, first person shooter (beach head) you get my point. Any suggestions on some articles out there using vb.net only?

Comment: I believe Unity supports VB.NET.  I've never used it, but that seems to be the latest big thing in .NET game development.

Comment: If you really want to use only VB.Net, you could use WPF or good old GDI+ (namespace `System.Drawing`). But that's only practical for 2D content. For 3D content, I would recommend some graphics API like Unity (as Steven suggested), SharpDX, SlimDX, OpenTK etc.

Comment: How about managed directx? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159586/Starting-DirectX-with-Visual-Basic-NET

Comment: Too Broad.. and tbh.  probably off topic as it isn't about a specific reproducible programming problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is yesno. 
You can buy an engine like unity , but you have to learn programing in vb.net again.
And you can build Mario by using picture boxes and some easy code.